# How to seed using a file other than seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails is possible to seed a database using a file other than `db/seeds.rb`?

As in, is there some way to specify an alternate seed file while running `rake db:reset`, along the lines of `rake db:reset --seedwith db/seeds2.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass switches into seeds.rb with environment variables, and seed different data accordingly.

```
SEED_DATA=set1 rake db:seed
SEED_DATA=set2 rake db:seed
```

In seed.rb,

```
if ENV['SEED_DATA'] == 'set1'
  ...
elsif ENV['SEED_DATA'] == 'set2'
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: This seems to answer the question to me. What's the problem?